# Publishing Public YouTube Videos via Internal Application on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube, youtube-api

I have a question regarding how to manage an application on Google Cloud Platform in terms of its accessibility, both internally and externally. I've developed an application on the Google Cloud Platform, generated OAuth credentials, and have been attempting to publish live videos on YouTube for public viewing using the API. However, I've received an email stating that my videos were changed to private. After investigating, I've identified that this issue is related to my application not being verified. I've noticed that if I manage the application internally, I might not need to go through the verification process, which would potentially allow only users within my organization to utilize the application.

My question is: if I change my application's settings to be internal and restricted to users within my organization, would it be possible to publish videos on YouTube as public without needing the application verification?